# Binary heap with O(1) lookup and O(log n) change key

Tags: c++, heap

I needed a priority queue that allowed efficient searching and changing of keys. I tried `std::priority_queue`, but the interface was extremely limiting. Not being able to search for existence wasn't a big deal since I could separately keep a `std::unordered_set<key_type>` around, but not being able to modify key value was a deal breaker.

I next sampled a `std::vector` maintained with `std::make_heap` and friends, but finding the element took \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time and changing the key value took \$3n\$ operations since I had to `std::make_heap` the entire sequence.

Here is my binary heap with these guarantees:

- \$\Theta(1)\$ time search
- \$\Theta(n)\$ time construction and batch insert
- \$\Theta(\log n)\$ time insert
- \$\Theta(\log n)\$ time extract top
- \$\Theta(\log n)\$ time change key (and check key if value was indirectly changed)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#define SENTINEL(T) (T{})

namespace sal {

// by default maxheap where parent greater than children
template <typename T, typename Cmp = std::greater<T>>
class Heap {    
    // default representation is as a vector, index at 1 so need 1 extra element
    std::vector<T> elems;
    // associate each key with an index
    std::unordered_map<T,size_t> index;
    // comparator for sorting in a maxheap
    Cmp cmp;
    size_t parent(size_t i) {return i >> 1;}
    size_t left(size_t i) {return i << 1;}
    size_t right(size_t i) {return (i << 1) + 1;}
    // runs in O(n) time, produces max heap from unordered input array
    void build_heap() {
        // second half of elems are leaves, 1 elem is maxheap by default
        for (size_t i = elems.size() >> 1; i != 0; --i) 
            heapify(i);
    }
    // adjusts elems[i] assuming it's been modified to be smaller than its children
    // runs in O(lgn) time, floats elems[i] down
    void heapify(size_t i) {
        while (true) {
            size_t l = left(i), r = right(i);
            size_t largest = i; 
            // largest of elems[i], elems[l], and elems[r]
            if (l < elems.size() && cmp(elems[l], elems[i]))
                largest = l;
            if (r < elems.size() && cmp(elems[r], elems[largest]))
                largest = r;
            // do until elems[i] is max heap
            if (largest == i) break;
            swap(elems[i], elems[largest]);
            swap(index[elems[i]], index[elems[largest]]);
            i = largest;
        }
    }
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
    // default T value as sentinel

    // construction ------------
    // O(n) time construction via these constructors (would be O(nlgn) for repeated inserts)
    Heap(Cmp& c) : elems{T{}}, cmp(c) {}
    Heap(initializer_list<T> l, Cmp&& c = Cmp{}) : cmp(c) {
        elems.reserve(l.size()+1);
        elems.push_back(SENTINEL(T));
        for (const T& v : l) {index[v] = elems.size(); elems.push_back(v);}
        build_heap();
    }
    template <typename Iter>
    Heap(Iter begin, Iter end, Cmp&& c = Cmp{}) : cmp(c) {
        elems.reserve(end - begin + 1);
        elems.push_back(SENTINEL(T));
        while (begin != end) {index[*begin] = elems.size(); elems.push_back(*begin); ++begin;}
        build_heap();
    }

    // query ---------------
    bool empty() const  {return elems.size() <= 1;}
    size_t size() const {return elems.size() - 1;}
    T top() const       {return elems[1];}
    // index of key, 0 means key not found
    size_t key(T k) const {
        auto itr = index.find(k);
        return (itr == index.end())? 0 : itr->second;
    }

    // extraction ----------
    // runs in O(lgn) time due to heapify
    T extract_top() {
        // heap underflow
        if (elems.size() <= 1) return SENTINEL(T); 

        T top {elems[1]};
        swap(elems[1],elems.back());
        index[elems[1]] = 1;

        index.erase(elems.back());
        elems.pop_back();
        heapify(1);
        return top;
    }

    // modification ----------
    void insert(T key) {
        index[key] = elems.size();
        elems.push_back(key);
        check_key(elems.size()-1);
    }
    // O(n) like constructor for all elements
    template <typename Iter>
    void batch_insert(Iter begin, Iter end) {
        while (begin != end) {index[*begin] = elems.size(); elems.push_back(*begin); ++begin;}
        build_heap();
    }
    // repeadtedly compare against parent
    void change_key(size_t i, T key) {
        // change should only float up (so only increase on maxheap and decrease on minheap)
        if (cmp(elems[i], key)) return;
        elems[i] = key;
        while (i > 1 && cmp(elems[i], elems[parent(i)])) {
            swap(elems[i], elems[parent(i)]);
            swap(index[elems[i]], index[elems[parent(i)]]);
            i = parent(i);
        }
    }
    // float value up if its value was changed indirectly (through comparator)
    void check_key(size_t i) {
        while (i > 1 && cmp(elems[i], elems[parent(i)])) {
            swap(elems[i], elems[parent(i)]);
            swap(index[elems[i]], index[elems[parent(i)]]);
            i = parent(i);
        }       
    }


    // iteration -------------
    iterator begin() {return elems.begin() + 1;}
    iterator end()   {return elems.end();}
    const_iterator begin() const {return elems.cbegin() + 1;}
    const_iterator end() const   {return elems.cend();}

    bool is_maxheap() const {return std::is_heap(elems.begin()+1, elems.end(), cmp);}
    bool is_minheap() const {return std::is_heap(elems.rbegin(), elems.rend()-1, cmp);}
    bool correct_index() const {
        for (auto itr : index) if (itr.first != elems[itr.second])
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};

}
```

I realized that the current implementation would be inefficient and broken for complex data (non-POD in C++), so I made a slightly modified version working with pointers when the type isn't POD.

```
// differentiate the implementation based on whether data is simple
template <typename T, typename Cmp = std::greater<T>, bool ispod = false>
struct Heap_impl {};

// iterator wrappers for non-POD types
// only different is operator* which does 2 levels of dereference
template <typename Iter>
struct Heap_iterator {
    using CR = const Heap_iterator<Iter>&;
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<typename Iter::value_type>::value_type;
    Iter cur;

    void operator++() {++cur;}
    void operator--() {--cur;}
    Heap_iterator operator++(int) {return {cur++};}
    Heap_iterator operator--(int) {return {cur--};}
    T& operator*() {return **cur;}
    Iter& operator->() {return cur;}
    bool operator==(CR other) {return other.cur == cur;}
    bool operator!=(CR other) {return !(*this == other);}
};
template <typename Iter>
struct Heap_const_iterator {
    using CR = const Heap_const_iterator<Iter>&;
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<typename Iter::value_type>::value_type;
    Iter cur;

    void operator++() {++cur;}
    void operator--() {--cur;}
    Heap_const_iterator operator++(int) {return {cur++};}
    Heap_const_iterator operator--(int) {return {cur--};}
    T operator*() const {return **cur;}
    const Iter& operator->() const {return cur;}
    bool operator==(CR other) {return other.cur == cur;}
    bool operator!=(CR other) {return !(*this == other);}
};

// for non-PODs, hold pointers to only 1 copy of data
// pointers are relatively small and easily swappable
template <typename T, typename Cmp>
class Heap_impl<T, Cmp, false>{ 
    // in case raw pointer gets swapped out for std::shared_ptr
    using TP = T*;
    // hash on the data pointed to
    struct TP_hash {
        size_t operator()(const TP& vp) const {
            return std::hash<T>()(*vp);
        }
    };
    // equality on data pointed to
    struct TP_equal {
        bool operator()(const TP& a, const TP& b) const {
            return *a == *b;
        }
    };
    // default representation is as a vector, index at 1 so need 1 extra element
    std::vector<TP> elems;
    // associate each key with an index, hash with value pointed by
    std::unordered_map<TP, size_t, TP_hash, TP_equal> index;
    // comparator
    Cmp cmp;
    size_t parent(size_t i) {return i >> 1;}
    size_t left(size_t i) {return i << 1;}
    size_t right(size_t i) {return (i << 1) + 1;}

    // create only 1 actual copy of the data
    void push_back(const T& v) {
        TP actual_value {new T{v}};
        index[actual_value] = elems.size();
        elems.push_back(actual_value);
    }
    // runs in O(n) time, produces max heap from unordered input array
    void build_heap() {
        // second half of elems are leaves, 1 elem is maxheap by default
        for (size_t i = elems.size() >> 1; i != 0; --i) 
            heapify(i);
    }
    // adjusts elems[i] assuming it's been modified to be smaller than its children
    // runs in O(lgn) time, floats elems[i] down
    void heapify(size_t i) {
        while (true) {
            size_t l = left(i), r = right(i);
            size_t largest = i; 
            // largest of elems[i], elems[l], and elems[r]
            if (l < elems.size() && cmp(*elems[l], *elems[i]))
                largest = l;
            if (r < elems.size() && cmp(*elems[r], *elems[largest]))
                largest = r;
            // do until elems[i] is max heap
            if (largest == i) break;
            std::swap(elems[i], elems[largest]);
            std::swap(index[elems[i]], index[elems[largest]]);
            i = largest;
        }
    }
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = Heap_iterator<typename std::vector<TP>::iterator>;
    using const_iterator = Heap_const_iterator<typename std::vector<TP>::const_iterator>;

    // construction ------------
    // O(n) time construction via these constructors (would be O(nlgn) for repeated inserts)
    Heap_impl(Cmp& c) : elems{nullptr}, cmp(c) {}
    Heap_impl(std::initializer_list<T> l, Cmp&& c = Cmp{}) : cmp(c) {
        elems.reserve(l.size()+1);
        elems.push_back(nullptr);
        for (const T& v : l) push_back(v);
        build_heap();
    }
    template <typename Iter>
    Heap_impl(Iter begin, Iter end, Cmp&& c = Cmp{}) : cmp(c) {
        elems.reserve(end - begin + 1);
        elems.push_back(nullptr);
        while (begin != end) {push_back(*begin); ++begin;}
        build_heap();
    }
    ~Heap_impl() {for (TP p : elems) delete p;}

    // query ---------------
    bool empty() const  {return elems.size() <= 1;}
    size_t size() const {return elems.size() - 1;}
    T top() const       {return *elems[1];}
    // index of key, 0 means key not found
    size_t key(const T& k) const {
        TP kp {&k};
        auto itr = index.find(kp);
        return (itr == index.end())? 0 : itr->second;
    }
    // for temporary references 
    size_t key(T&& k) const {
        TP kp {&k};
        auto itr = index.find(kp);
        return (itr == index.end())? 0 : itr->second;
    }

    // extraction ----------
    // runs in O(lgn) time due to heapify
    T extract_top() {
        // heap underflow
        if (elems.size() <= 1) return T{}; 

        T top {*elems[1]};
        std::swap(elems[1],elems.back());
        index[elems[1]] = 1;

        index.erase(elems.back());
        delete elems.back();
        elems.pop_back();

        heapify(1);
        return top;
    }

    // modification ----------
    void insert(const T& key) {
        push_back(key);
        check_key(elems.size()-1);
    }
    // O(n) like constructor for all elements
    template <typename Iter>
    void batch_insert(Iter begin, Iter end) {
        while (begin != end) {push_back(*begin); ++begin;}
        build_heap();
    }
    // repeadtedly compare against parent
    void change_key(size_t i, const T& key) {
        // change should only float up (so only increase on maxheap and decrease on minheap)
        if (cmp(*elems[i], key)) return;
        index.erase(elems[i]);
        delete elems[i];

        elems[i] = new TP{key};

        index[elems[i]] = i;

        while (i > 1 && cmp(elems[i], elems[parent(i)])) {
            std::swap(elems[i], elems[parent(i)]);
            std::swap(index[elems[i]], index[elems[parent(i)]]);
            i = parent(i);
        }
    }
    void change_val(const T& old, const T& changed) {
        change_key(key(old), changed);
    }
    // float value up if its value was changed indirectly (through comparator)
    void check_key(size_t i) {
        while (i > 1 && cmp(*elems[i], *elems[parent(i)])) {
            std::swap(elems[i], elems[parent(i)]);
            std::swap(index[elems[i]], index[elems[parent(i)]]);
            i = parent(i);
        }       
    }

    // iteration -------------
    iterator begin() {return {elems.begin() + 1};}
    iterator end()   {return {elems.end()};}
    const_iterator begin() const {return {elems.begin() + 1};}
    const_iterator end() const   {return {elems.end()};}

    // bool is_maxheap() const {return std::is_heap(elems.begin()+1, elems.end(), cmp);}
    // bool is_minheap() const {return std::is_heap(elems.rbegin(), elems.rend()-1, cmp);}
    bool correct_index() const {
        for (auto itr : index) if (itr.first != elems[itr.second])
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};
```

---

```
// implementation for POD types from above...

// exposed interface, auto type dispatch
template <typename T, typename Cmp = std::greater<T>>
using Heap = Heap_impl<T, Cmp, std::is_pod<T>::value>;
```

Comment: If you've made an improvement *before receiving answers*, you should just replace the old code with the new code (unless they're different implementations and can both be reviewed).

Comment: They are complementary implementations since I kept the old one for simple data but simply added a type dispatch so that the new implementation only applied to non-simple data. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Strictly speaking, `unordered_map::find` is not O(1). It's upper bound is the same as the upper bound on the number of collisions produced by `hash`.

Comment: I think any decent hash table implementation is going to have worst case amortized O(1) lookup. Talking about worst case complexities for a single operation doesn't really make sense in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the public API of `Heap<T>` is

```
bool empty() const
bool size() const
T top() const
size_t key(T) const
T extract_top()
void insert(T)
template<class Iter> void batch_insert(Iter, Iter)
void change_key(size_t, T)
void check_key(size_t)
bool is_maxheap() const
bool is_minheap() const
bool correct_index() const
```

Some of these names match the STL containers very well (e.g. `empty()` and `size()`), but some of them are completely opaque to me (e.g. `is_maxheap()`, `correct_index()`). It would be nice if `Heap<T>` behaved more like an STL container, wherever possible.

---

The existence of `T top() const` implies that `Heap<T>` cannot be used with non-copyable `T`s, and is inefficient even for copyable `T`s. It would make more sense to provide a `top()` method along the same lines as `std::queue<T>::front()`:

```
T& top();
const T& top() const;
```

---

In the iterator class:

```
void operator++() {++cur;}
```

Of course you mean

```
auto& operator++() { ++cur; return *this; }
auto operator++(int) { auto result = *this; ++*this; return result; }
```

---

```
typename Cmp = std::greater<T>
```

In C++14, it would be preferable to specify [`Cmp = std::greater<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void). I don't know of any best-practices way of saying "use `greater<>` but degrade gracefully to `greater<T>` in C++11."

---

`batch_insert(Iter, Iter)` sounds an awful lot like what the STL calls `insert(Iter, Iter)`. Function overloading does suck, but inconsistency sucks more. Prefer to copy the STL's naming convention in this case.

---

In your version "for non-POD `T`": This should be your only version. The POD-ness of `T` isn't important; what's important is whether the type is expensive to copy or not.

```
TP actual_value {new T{v}};
```

You should be using smart pointers; i.e., this should be `auto actual_value = make_unique<T>(v)`. Otherwise, you risk memory leaks if any of the later lines in this function throw an exception.

Also, you should be using perfect forwarding (`std::forward<V>(v)`) to eliminate unnecessary copies in the case that `v` is copyable, and to eliminate compiler diagnostics in the case that `v` is non-copyable.

---

Speaking of move semantics,

```
Heap(Cmp& c) : elems{T{}}, cmp(c) {}
Heap(initializer_list<T> l, Cmp&& c = Cmp{}) : cmp(c) { ... }
```

These are both incorrect. What you meant is

```
Heap(Cmp c) : elems{T{}}, cmp(std::move(c)) {}
Heap(initializer_list<T> l, Cmp c = Cmp{}) : cmp(std::move(c)) { ... }
```

Specifying the parameter as `Cmp&` means that the user can't pass in a reference to a const lvalue, nor can he pass in an rvalue expression.

Specifying the parameter as `Cmp&&` means that the user can't pass in any kind of lvalue (const or not), which means the user can't pass in any kind of named object.

What you wanted was simply `Cmp`, which means "I don't care what the user gives me, as long as it's possible to (implicitly) construct a `Cmp` from it." Once we've got that `Cmp` object on the stack, the next thing we do is obviously to `std::move` it into the right place.

---

```
swap(elems[1],elems.back());
```

This should be

```
using std::swap;
swap(elems[1],elems.back());
```

Otherwise, the code won't even compile for something like `Heap<int>`, because there's no such thing as a free function `swap(int, int)`. You have to make sure that name lookup will correctly find `std::swap` if ADL fails.

(If it's been working for you because you `using namespace std;` at file scope before including this header, then your code is bad and you should feel bad.)

---

Stylistically, the code is a bit dense, especially with all those confusingly-named public member functions. I didn't spend any time trying to puzzle out what `correct_index()` was meant to do, for example. I would recommend putting a single blank line between member function definitions; and making sure member functions are `private` when appropriate; and making sure that member functions' names match the STL conventions whenever possible.

---

Finally: Isn't the "change_key" operation just the same thing as removing the pair {key1, value1} and then inserting the new pair {key2, value1}? What's the point of providing it as a primitive operation?— can you actually do it more efficiently than "remove and re-insert"?

Comment: For initialization with Cmp&&, isn't this a universal reference since Cmp is a template/deduced type? This would then be either an rvalue reference if an rvalue was passed in, or an lvalue if an lvalue was passed in.

Comment: No, `Cmp` is a template parameter type *to the class template*, but by the time you get around to calling the constructor of a particular specialization of the class template, you definitely know what `Cmp` is for *that* class, so `Cmp` is never deduced. Therefore `Cmp&&` is just a plain old rvalue reference; it's not a universal/forwarding reference in that context.